# Woo-commerce категории

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Как найти текст который был написан в описании категории товара woocommerce? 
Вроде бы текст пишется в wp_posts, а категории в wp_terms. Нахожу название в категориях но не нахожу текст в wp_posts.

Что делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Ищите описание термов в метатаблице термов `wp_termmeta`.

Comment: Спасибо, на новой версии сайта вижу текста, но на старой там почему то ничего нет

Comment: На старой версии описания то выводятся? Таблица `wp_termmeta` появилась не так давно.

Comment: выводились, но от старой версии сайта осталось только база данных